# "Unresolved reference: implementation" by using subprojects in kotlin-gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I want to split my project into subprojects. The default Gradle setting from the IntelliJ IDE is:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50"
}

group = "project"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

That setting compiles. ButI don't want repeat that code in every subproject. So I changed the *build.gradle.kts* to

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

subprojects {
    plugins {
        kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50"
    }

    group = "project"
    version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    }

    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

but I get the exception:

> e: C:[...]\build.gradle.kts:1:12: Unresolved reference: jetbrains e:
> C:[...]\build.gradle.kts:16:9: Unresolved reference: implementation
> e: C:[...]\build.gradle.kts:19:20: Unresolved reference:
> KotlinCompile e: C:[...]\build.gradle.kts:19:35: Type mismatch:
> inferred type is () -> Unit but Class<TypeVariable(S)!>! was expected
> e: C:[...]\build.gradle.kts:20:9: Unresolved reference: kotlinOptions
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'C:[...]\build.gradle.kts' line: 1
> - What went wrong: Script compilation errors:
>
>   Line 01: import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
>   ^ Unresolved reference: jetbrains
>
>   Line 16:         implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
>   ^ Unresolved reference: implementation
>
>   Line 19:     tasks.withType {
>   ^ Unresolved reference: KotlinCompile
>
>   Line 19:     tasks.withType {
>   ^ Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Unit but Class<TypeVariable(S)!>! was expected
>
>   Line 20:         kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
>   ^ Unresolved reference: kotlinOptions
>
> 5 errors
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s

I think there is an easy syntax error, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Not sure how you're not also getting an error by nesting the `plugins { }` block under `subprojects { }` As stated in [Limitations of the plugins DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#plugins_dsl_limitations):

> The `plugins {}` block must also be a top level statement in the buildscript. It cannot be nested inside another construct (e.g. an if-statement or for-loop).

So to fix your issues, move the `plugins {}` to the top and imperatively apply the plugins in the `subprojects {}` block:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50" apply false
}

subprojects {
    apply {
        plugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    }

    group = "project"
    version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    val implementation by configurations

    dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    }

    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

You can read more about the `apply false` part in the [Method details](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependenciesSpec.html#N1B5D2) of `PluginDependenciesSpec` which is the *type*/scope of the `plugins {}` block.

You can read more about the `val implementation by configurations` part in the [Understanding what to do when type-safe model accessors are not available](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin_using_standard_api)

Comment: You singlehandedly saved one of my projects. All the documentation I found on Gradle's website was completely useless. Your post, on the other hand, had me up and running in five minutes.
Gradle should fire all their documentation department and hire you instead.

Answer (score 2):

Is important to define the repositories in `settings.gradle.kts (project)` so that the dependencies of the subprojects are recognized.

### settings.gradle.kts (project)

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
        mavenCentral()
        maven("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    }
}
rootProject.name = "project"

include("app")
```

---

### build.gradle.kts (project)

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

        plugins {
            java
            kotlin("jvm") version "1.4-M3" apply false
        }

subprojects {
    apply {
        plugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    }

    repositories {
        maven("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
        mavenCentral()
    }

    val implementation by configurations

    dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    }

    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

---

To define plugins for each submodule separately use the lambda `apply { plugin("pluginId") }`

### build.gradle.kts (:app)

```
apply {
    plugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}
```

GL